# Image crops uncontrollably different for different products in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, thumbnails

I am working with Woocommerce since last week and uploading the products portfolio for the online store. The problem I am having is that even though Woocommerce settings dictate products to have 1x1 ration crops with 300x300 px resolution for Featured images, I have two different sized featured images for two different products:

1. 450x450 - http://www.thamon.co.uk/product/leaf-beauty-bag/
2. 450x300 - http://www.thamon.co.uk/product/leaf-slippers/

Two questions:

1. What should I do to make the thumbnails even?
2. Where can I control the dimensions of the photo instead of cropping them? I have photoshopped images to have same size and resolution, I would like to use those photos without unnecessary cropping, so basically keep them with the ration like in the 2nd example I posted (450x300px)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to refresh the thumbnails since you changed them in the woocommerce settings.  You can do this easily with this plugin.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

As far as leaving them uncropped and changing the size, just do this in a image editor.  Otherwise there are several ways to do it.  You can do it in the code which handles the image size or by changing the max width and max height in your css for that specific class.

Hope that helps.